# On Ruby: uninitialized constant Nokogiri::ClassResolver (NameError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nameerror

I've this issue currently when launching my .rb, that says  `` 1: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.13.1-x86_64-linux/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:56:in `<module:XML>' /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.13.1-x86_64-linux/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:59:in `<class:Node>': uninitialized constant Nokogiri::ClassResolver (NameError) ``

I've put theses lines in my .rb :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.google.com/search?q=doughnuts'))
puts doc
```

and my Gemfile contains this :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.7.4'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'open-uri'
```

Does anyone have any idea about the problem or oversight that is causing this error?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know now, it seems to be an issue linked to usr/local/bin permissions (I'm working with a VM on Xubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

The "nokogiri" package updates version might have bugs so try to install lower version of nokogiri package after removes the new version....Try this,

I am not sure about it, I have read it in one senior developer post.

Answer (score 0):

The following fixed it for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove ruby-nokogiri
```

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem for me:

```
require 'nokogiri/class_resolver'
require 'nokogiri'
```

Requiring the file that defines the constant (class_resolver) before the file that uses it makes it available, and therefore no error.